# Simulating an egg on a conveyor belt getting smashed

Tags: physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I have a short animation of an egg shape (solid w/o liquid) and the egg is on a conveyor belt (follows directional movement of belt via driver) then was supposed to have the egg get smashed by a large fist.

I've successfully gotten the egg to follow the track but I can't figure out how to use something like cell fracture without being able to follow the track and stay in one piece.

I wanted the egg shape to be able to collide and fall apart with the fist.
Fist and belt are both passive.

Here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/129oaacQeLD6FqnUE0aJXJ1Y1ITYI09mm/view?usp=sharing) to what I have so far for the blend file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this yet?  I use the explode modifier in cases like this

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this with the help of the Fracture Modifier Build of blender.
You can find more info and download it here:

http://graphicall.org/1148

I also included the steps in a text file inside the modified blend. Open this blend only in the Fracture Modifier Build or you may experience crashes and data loss in the blend.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- delete the cell fracture objects
- put fracture modifier on original egg, 250 shards, execute fracture
- egg becomes convexhull, active, animated, triggered
- fist becomes convexhull, active, animated, trigger
- belt becomes passive animated, mesh, final, deforming (so it can 
  move the egg shards too)
- scene / rigidbodyworld: enable split impulse (less velocity on shards on
  on fist impact, basically) and steps per second to 600 (so shards dont fall
  so much thru the belt)
- optionally: in FM enable Fracture Utilties -> Fix Normals and refracture 
  with Execute fracture, set Autohide distance to 0.001 and automerge distance
  to 0.1 and enable perform merge, to hide the cracks in the smoothed egg 
  shell
- optionally: add edgesplit and subsurf for a nicer looking egg surface